# disable textbox by getting element by id and class name

Tags: javascript

I want to disable by a textbox using a class name and id. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work. It works if I get the elements by just an Id.

```js
function disableText() {

  var textbox = document.getElementByClassName("text");
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {

    textbox[0].disabled = true;


  } else {
    textbox[0].disabled = false;

  }


}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="check" onclick="disableText()">

<input class="text" type="textbox">
```

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName()`, plural "elements", and it returns a list of matching elements.

Comment: You are missing the trigger event that calls your function, it could be "on_click" over the checkbox control.

Comment: also it should be `disabled` past tense not `disable`, `onclick` or `onchange` then `="disableText()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two typos and no trigger are the problem.

Typos:

- `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` (plural Elements)
- `disable` should be `disabled` (past tense)

Trigger:

- `onchange`, `onclick`, `oninput` then `="disableText()"` on the checkbox

```js
function disableText() {
  var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {

    textbox[0].disabled = true;


  } else {
    textbox[0].disabled = false;

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="check" onclick="disableText()">

<input class="text" type="textbox">
```

Or to not use checkbox validation at all just set disabled to checkbox value

```js
function disableText() {
  var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
  textbox[0].disabled = document.getElementById("check").checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="check" onclick="disableText()">

<input class="text" type="textbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one line, without JS inside HTML code.

```js
check.onclick = () => {document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].disabled = check.checked};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="check">
<input class="text" type="textbox">
```